# Does Toad force bind variable in queries?

Tags: oracle, optimization

I've seen that when I execute a query Toad is forcing bind variable.
To help toad doing so I need to use the following hint: /*+ cursor_sharing_exact */

Is it possible to force toad not to use bind variable for queries which contains literals?

Comment: What version of TOAD are you running?  Go to toadworld.com for product-specific support.

Comment: When I run a query in TOAD with literals in it, and then look at the SGA, I don't see the literals replaced with bind variables.  I have default settings on.

Comment: Toad 11.0.0.0.116, other collegues don't have the same problem with other version.